# How to Save an audio file and play the decibels in a level

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hello I have a project that records the audio input and shows the decibel levels on a scale like a level, anyway I am trying to find a way to link it to a tableview so that I can save the recordings it can play them as soon as it gets recorded here is my code it is quite long so I will just give you the playback and recording code if any other code is needed please comment below.

### here is the code:

AQplayer.m

```
#include "AQPlayer.h"

void AQPlayer::AQBufferCallback(void *                  inUserData,
                                AudioQueueRef           inAQ,
                                AudioQueueBufferRef     inCompleteAQBuffer) 
{
    AQPlayer *THIS = (AQPlayer *)inUserData;

    if (THIS->mIsDone) return;

    UInt32 numBytes;
    UInt32 nPackets = THIS->GetNumPacketsToRead();
    OSStatus result = AudioFileReadPackets(THIS->GetAudioFileID(), false, &numBytes, inCompleteAQBuffer->mPacketDescriptions, THIS->GetCurrentPacket(), &nPackets, 
                                           inCompleteAQBuffer->mAudioData);
    if (result)
        printf("AudioFileReadPackets failed: %d", (int)result);
    if (nPackets > 0) {
        inCompleteAQBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize = numBytes;      
        inCompleteAQBuffer->mPacketDescriptionCount = nPackets;     
        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inCompleteAQBuffer, 0, NULL);
        THIS->mCurrentPacket = (THIS->GetCurrentPacket() + nPackets);
    } 

    else 
    {
        if (THIS->IsLooping())
        {
            THIS->mCurrentPacket = 0;
            AQBufferCallback(inUserData, inAQ, inCompleteAQBuffer);
        }
        else
        {
            // stop
            THIS->mIsDone = true;
            AudioQueueStop(inAQ, false);
        }
    }
}

void AQPlayer::isRunningProc (  void *              inUserData,
                                AudioQueueRef           inAQ,
                                AudioQueuePropertyID    inID)
{
    AQPlayer *THIS = (AQPlayer *)inUserData;
    UInt32 size = sizeof(THIS->mIsRunning);
    OSStatus result = AudioQueueGetProperty (inAQ, kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning, &THIS->mIsRunning, &size);

    if ((result == noErr) && (!THIS->mIsRunning))
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"playbackQueueStopped" object: nil];
}

void AQPlayer::CalculateBytesForTime (CAStreamBasicDescription & inDesc, UInt32 inMaxPacketSize, Float64 inSeconds, UInt32 *outBufferSize, UInt32 *outNumPackets)
{
    // we only use time here as a guideline
    // we're really trying to get somewhere between 16K and 64K buffers, but not allocate too much if we don't need it
    static const int maxBufferSize = 0x10000; // limit size to 64K
    static const int minBufferSize = 0x4000; // limit size to 16K

    if (inDesc.mFramesPerPacket) {
        Float64 numPacketsForTime = inDesc.mSampleRate / inDesc.mFramesPerPacket * inSeconds;
        *outBufferSize = numPacketsForTime * inMaxPacketSize;
    } else {
        // if frames per packet is zero, then the codec has no predictable packet == time
        // so we can't tailor this (we don't know how many Packets represent a time period
        // we'll just return a default buffer size
        *outBufferSize = maxBufferSize > inMaxPacketSize ? maxBufferSize : inMaxPacketSize;
    }

    // we're going to limit our size to our default
    if (*outBufferSize > maxBufferSize && *outBufferSize > inMaxPacketSize)
        *outBufferSize = maxBufferSize;
    else {
        // also make sure we're not too small - we don't want to go the disk for too small chunks
        if (*outBufferSize < minBufferSize)
            *outBufferSize = minBufferSize;
    }
    *outNumPackets = *outBufferSize / inMaxPacketSize;
}

AQPlayer::AQPlayer() :
    mQueue(0),
    mAudioFile(0),
    mFilePath(NULL),
    mIsRunning(false),
    mIsInitialized(false),
    mNumPacketsToRead(0),
    mCurrentPacket(0),
    mIsDone(false),
    mIsLooping(false) { }

AQPlayer::~AQPlayer() 
{
    DisposeQueue(true);
}

OSStatus AQPlayer::StartQueue(BOOL inResume)
{   
    // if we have a file but no queue, create one now
    if ((mQueue == NULL) && (mFilePath != NULL)) CreateQueueForFile(mFilePath);

    mIsDone = false;

    // if we are not resuming, we also should restart the file read index
    if (!inResume) {
        mCurrentPacket = 0;

        // prime the queue with some data before starting
        for (int i = 0; i < kNumberBuffers; ++i) {
            AQBufferCallback (this, mQueue, mBuffers[i]);           
        }
    }
    return AudioQueueStart(mQueue, NULL);
}

OSStatus AQPlayer::StopQueue()
{
    mIsDone = true;

    OSStatus result = AudioQueueStop(mQueue, true);
    if (result) printf("ERROR STOPPING QUEUE!\n");

    return result;
}

OSStatus AQPlayer::PauseQueue()
{
    OSStatus result = AudioQueuePause(mQueue);

    return result;
}

void AQPlayer::CreateQueueForFile(CFStringRef inFilePath) 
{   
    CFURLRef sndFile = NULL; 

    try {
        if (mFilePath == NULL)
        {
            mIsLooping = false;

            sndFile = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, inFilePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
            if (!sndFile) { printf("can't parse file path\n"); return; }

            OSStatus rc = AudioFileOpenURL (sndFile, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0/*inFileTypeHint*/, &mAudioFile);
            CFRelease(sndFile); // release sndFile here to quiet analyzer
            XThrowIfError(rc, "can't open file");

            UInt32 size = sizeof(mDataFormat);
            XThrowIfError(AudioFileGetProperty(mAudioFile, kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat, &size, &mDataFormat), "couldn't get file's data format");
            mFilePath = CFStringCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, inFilePath);
        }
        SetupNewQueue();        
    }
    catch (CAXException e) {
        char buf[256];
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (%s)\n", e.mOperation, e.FormatError(buf));
    }
}

void AQPlayer::SetupNewQueue() 
{
    XThrowIfError(AudioQueueNewOutput(&mDataFormat, AQPlayer::AQBufferCallback, this, 
                                        CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 0, &mQueue), "AudioQueueNew failed");
    UInt32 bufferByteSize;      
    // we need to calculate how many packets we read at a time, and how big a buffer we need
    // we base this on the size of the packets in the file and an approximate duration for each buffer
    // first check to see what the max size of a packet is - if it is bigger
    // than our allocation default size, that needs to become larger
    UInt32 maxPacketSize;
    UInt32 size = sizeof(maxPacketSize);
    XThrowIfError(AudioFileGetProperty(mAudioFile, 
                                       kAudioFilePropertyPacketSizeUpperBound, &size, &maxPacketSize), "couldn't get file's max packet size");

    // adjust buffer size to represent about a half second of audio based on this format
    CalculateBytesForTime (mDataFormat, maxPacketSize, kBufferDurationSeconds, &bufferByteSize, &mNumPacketsToRead);

        //printf ("Buffer Byte Size: %d, Num Packets to Read: %d\n", (int)bufferByteSize, (int)mNumPacketsToRead);

    // (2) If the file has a cookie, we should get it and set it on the AQ
    size = sizeof(UInt32);
    OSStatus result = AudioFileGetPropertyInfo (mAudioFile, kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, &size, NULL);

    if (!result && size) {
        char* cookie = new char [size];     
        XThrowIfError (AudioFileGetProperty (mAudioFile, kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, &size, cookie), "get cookie from file");
        XThrowIfError (AudioQueueSetProperty(mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_MagicCookie, cookie, size), "set cookie on queue");
        delete [] cookie;
    }

    // channel layout?
    result = AudioFileGetPropertyInfo(mAudioFile, kAudioFilePropertyChannelLayout, &size, NULL);
    if (result == noErr && size > 0) {
        AudioChannelLayout *acl = (AudioChannelLayout *)malloc(size);

        result = AudioFileGetProperty(mAudioFile, kAudioFilePropertyChannelLayout, &size, acl);
        if (result) { free(acl); XThrowIfError(result, "get audio file's channel layout"); }

        result = AudioQueueSetProperty(mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_ChannelLayout, acl, size);
        if (result){ free(acl); XThrowIfError(result, "set channel layout on queue"); }

        free(acl);
    }

    XThrowIfError(AudioQueueAddPropertyListener(mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning, isRunningProc, this), "adding property listener");

    bool isFormatVBR = (mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket == 0 || mDataFormat.mFramesPerPacket == 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < kNumberBuffers; ++i) {
        XThrowIfError(AudioQueueAllocateBufferWithPacketDescriptions(mQueue, bufferByteSize, (isFormatVBR ? mNumPacketsToRead : 0), &mBuffers[i]), "AudioQueueAllocateBuffer failed");
    }   

    // set the volume of the queue
    XThrowIfError (AudioQueueSetParameter(mQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, 1.0), "set queue volume");

    mIsInitialized = true;
}

void AQPlayer::DisposeQueue(Boolean inDisposeFile)
{
    if (mQueue)
    {
        AudioQueueDispose(mQueue, true);
        mQueue = NULL;
    }
    if (inDisposeFile)
    {
        if (mAudioFile)
        {       
            AudioFileClose(mAudioFile);
            mAudioFile = 0;
        }
        if (mFilePath)
        {
            CFRelease(mFilePath);
            mFilePath = NULL;
        }
    }
    mIsInitialized = false;
}
```

---

AQPlayerRecorder

```
#include "AQRecorder.h"

// ____________________________________________________________________________________
// Determine the size, in bytes, of a buffer necessary to represent the supplied number
// of seconds of audio data.
int AQRecorder::ComputeRecordBufferSize(const AudioStreamBasicDescription *format, float seconds)
{
    int packets, frames, bytes = 0;
    try {
        frames = (int)ceil(seconds * format->mSampleRate);

        if (format->mBytesPerFrame > 0)
            bytes = frames * format->mBytesPerFrame;
        else {
            UInt32 maxPacketSize;
            if (format->mBytesPerPacket > 0)
                maxPacketSize = format->mBytesPerPacket;    // constant packet size
            else {
                UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(maxPacketSize);
                XThrowIfError(AudioQueueGetProperty(mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_MaximumOutputPacketSize, &maxPacketSize,
                                                 &propertySize), "couldn't get queue's maximum output packet size");
            }
            if (format->mFramesPerPacket > 0)
                packets = frames / format->mFramesPerPacket;
            else
                packets = frames;   // worst-case scenario: 1 frame in a packet
            if (packets == 0)       // sanity check
                packets = 1;
            bytes = packets * maxPacketSize;
        }
    } catch (CAXException e) {
        char buf[256];
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (%s)\n", e.mOperation, e.FormatError(buf));
        return 0;
    }   
    return bytes;
}

// ____________________________________________________________________________________
// AudioQueue callback function, called when an input buffers has been filled.
void AQRecorder::MyInputBufferHandler(  void *                              inUserData,
                                        AudioQueueRef                       inAQ,
                                        AudioQueueBufferRef                 inBuffer,
                                        const AudioTimeStamp *              inStartTime,
                                        UInt32                              inNumPackets,
                                        const AudioStreamPacketDescription* inPacketDesc)
{
    AQRecorder *aqr = (AQRecorder *)inUserData;
    try {
        if (inNumPackets > 0) {
            // write packets to file
            XThrowIfError(AudioFileWritePackets(aqr->mRecordFile, FALSE, inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize,
                                             inPacketDesc, aqr->mRecordPacket, &inNumPackets, inBuffer->mAudioData),
                       "AudioFileWritePackets failed");
            aqr->mRecordPacket += inNumPackets;
        }

        // if we're not stopping, re-enqueue the buffe so that it gets filled again
        if (aqr->IsRunning())
            XThrowIfError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inBuffer, 0, NULL), "AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer failed");
    } catch (CAXException e) {
        char buf[256];
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (%s)\n", e.mOperation, e.FormatError(buf));
    }
}

AQRecorder::AQRecorder()
{
    mIsRunning = false;
    mRecordPacket = 0;
}

AQRecorder::~AQRecorder()
{
    AudioQueueDispose(mQueue, TRUE);
    AudioFileClose(mRecordFile);
    if (mFileName) CFRelease(mFileName);
}

// ____________________________________________________________________________________
// Copy a queue's encoder's magic cookie to an audio file.
void AQRecorder::CopyEncoderCookieToFile()
{
    UInt32 propertySize;
    // get the magic cookie, if any, from the converter     
    OSStatus err = AudioQueueGetPropertySize(mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_MagicCookie, &propertySize);

    // we can get a noErr result and also a propertySize == 0
    // -- if the file format does support magic cookies, but this file doesn't have one.
    if (err == noErr && propertySize > 0) {
        Byte *magicCookie = new Byte[propertySize];
        UInt32 magicCookieSize;
        XThrowIfError(AudioQueueGetProperty(mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_MagicCookie, magicCookie, &propertySize), "get audio converter's magic cookie");
        magicCookieSize = propertySize; // the converter lies and tell us the wrong size

        // now set the magic cookie on the output file
        UInt32 willEatTheCookie = false;
        // the converter wants to give us one; will the file take it?
        err = AudioFileGetPropertyInfo(mRecordFile, kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, NULL, &willEatTheCookie);
        if (err == noErr && willEatTheCookie) {
            err = AudioFileSetProperty(mRecordFile, kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, magicCookieSize, magicCookie);
            XThrowIfError(err, "set audio file's magic cookie");
        }
        delete[] magicCookie;
    }
}

void AQRecorder::SetupAudioFormat(UInt32 inFormatID)
{
    memset(&mRecordFormat, 0, sizeof(mRecordFormat));

    UInt32 size = sizeof(mRecordFormat.mSampleRate);
    XThrowIfError(AudioSessionGetProperty(  kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareSampleRate,
                                        &size, 
                                        &mRecordFormat.mSampleRate), "couldn't get hardware sample rate");

    size = sizeof(mRecordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame);
    XThrowIfError(AudioSessionGetProperty(  kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareInputNumberChannels, 
                                        &size, 
                                        &mRecordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame), "couldn't get input channel count");

    mRecordFormat.mFormatID = inFormatID;
    if (inFormatID == kAudioFormatLinearPCM)
    {
        // if we want pcm, default to signed 16-bit little-endian
        mRecordFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
        mRecordFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
        mRecordFormat.mBytesPerPacket = mRecordFormat.mBytesPerFrame = (mRecordFormat.mBitsPerChannel / 8) * mRecordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
        mRecordFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    }
}

void AQRecorder::StartRecord(CFStringRef inRecordFile)
{
    int i, bufferByteSize;
    UInt32 size;
    CFURLRef url = nil;

    try {       
        mFileName = CFStringCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, inRecordFile);

        // specify the recording format
        SetupAudioFormat(kAudioFormatLinearPCM);

        // create the queue
        XThrowIfError(AudioQueueNewInput(
                                      &mRecordFormat,
                                      MyInputBufferHandler,
                                      this /* userData */,
                                      NULL /* run loop */, NULL /* run loop mode */,
                                      0 /* flags */, &mQueue), "AudioQueueNewInput failed");

        // get the record format back from the queue's audio converter --
        // the file may require a more specific stream description than was necessary to create the encoder.
        mRecordPacket = 0;

        size = sizeof(mRecordFormat);
        XThrowIfError(AudioQueueGetProperty(mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_StreamDescription,  
                                         &mRecordFormat, &size), "couldn't get queue's format");

        NSString *recordFile = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: (NSString*)inRecordFile];    

        url = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)recordFile, NULL);

        // create the audio file
        OSStatus status = AudioFileCreateWithURL(url, kAudioFileCAFType, &mRecordFormat, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &mRecordFile);
        CFRelease(url);

        XThrowIfError(status, "AudioFileCreateWithURL failed");

        // copy the cookie first to give the file object as much info as we can about the data going in
        // not necessary for pcm, but required for some compressed audio
        CopyEncoderCookieToFile();

        // allocate and enqueue buffers
        bufferByteSize = ComputeRecordBufferSize(&mRecordFormat, kBufferDurationSeconds);   // enough bytes for half a second
        for (i = 0; i < kNumberRecordBuffers; ++i) {
            XThrowIfError(AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(mQueue, bufferByteSize, &mBuffers[i]),
                       "AudioQueueAllocateBuffer failed");
            XThrowIfError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(mQueue, mBuffers[i], 0, NULL),
                       "AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer failed");
        }
        // start the queue
        mIsRunning = true;
        XThrowIfError(AudioQueueStart(mQueue, NULL), "AudioQueueStart failed");
    }
    catch (CAXException e) {
        char buf[256];
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (%s)\n", e.mOperation, e.FormatError(buf));
    }
    catch (...) {
        fprintf(stderr, "An unknown error occurred\n");;
    }   

}

void AQRecorder::StopRecord()
{
    // end recording
    mIsRunning = false;
    XThrowIfError(AudioQueueStop(mQueue, true), "AudioQueueStop failed");   
    // a codec may update its cookie at the end of an encoding session, so reapply it to the file now
    CopyEncoderCookieToFile();
    if (mFileName)
    {
        CFRelease(mFileName);
        mFileName = NULL;
    }
    AudioQueueDispose(mQueue, true);
    AudioFileClose(mRecordFile);
```

### }

Here is my SPEAKHEre.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "AQLevelMeter.h"

#import "AQPlayer.h"
#import "AQRecorder.h"


@interface SpeakHereController : NSObject {

    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem*   btn_record;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem*   btn_play;
    IBOutlet UILabel*           fileDescription;
    IBOutlet AQLevelMeter*      lvlMeter_in;

    AQPlayer*                   player;
    AQRecorder*                 recorder;
    BOOL                        playbackWasInterrupted;
    BOOL                        playbackWasPaused;

    CFStringRef                 recordFilePath; 
}

- (void)registerForBackgroundNotifications;

@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIBarButtonItem     *btn_record;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIBarButtonItem     *btn_play;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   UILabel             *fileDescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   AQLevelMeter        *lvlMeter_in;

@property (readonly)            AQPlayer            *player;
@property (readonly)            AQRecorder          *recorder;
@property                       BOOL                playbackWasInterrupted;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   BOOL                inBackground;

- (IBAction)record: (id) sender;
- (IBAction)play: (id) sender;

@end
```

Comment: Please help if I need to put anymore information up please let me know

Comment: Hi. you want to show recorded voice in Tableview and in detail view it should play